# How can I switch order names in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have my column `full_name` in the table `Student`, but the order of name is last name and first name

```
Smith, John
Brown, Jenny
```

And I would like to switch it to

```
John Smith
Jenny Brown
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Another good example why normalizing a data model is a good idea. Rather than _switching_ the values, you should consider re-designing your data model and create two separate columns.

Comment: I can't think of a single reason why you would have this instead of separate FirstName, LastName columns, from which you can obtain a FullName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting names into separate columns is the right way to go. You can use "split_part" to create 2 new columns in your data model.

```
    select full_name, 
     split_part(full_name, ',', 2) as first_name, 
     split_part(full_name, ',', 1) as last_name
    from student
```